# shopt -s nullglob unexpectedly affects read

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I expected both output to equal `foo [Required] bar` but upon setting `nullglob` the `[Required]` vanishes. Why?

I'm running MacOS.

Thanks!

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0)

$ shopt -u nullglob
$ read < <(echo "foo [Required] bar"); echo $REPLY;
foo [Required] bar

$ shopt -s nullglob
$ read < <(echo "foo [Required] bar"); echo $REPLY;
foo bar
```

Comment: Always run your scripts through shellcheck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't quote the variable `$REPLY`, filename expansion is done after expanding the variable.

`[Required]` is a filename wildcard pattern. It will match any of the following characters: `R`, `e`, `q`, `u`, `i`, `r`, `d`.

You presumably don't have any filenames like that. The `nullglob` option means that a wildcard that doesn't match anything should be replaced with a null string rather than being left unexpanded.

Moral of the story: quote your variables unless you want them to undergo filename expansion.

Comment: :facepalm: Oops... Thanks!!

Comment: Ah, in my actual code I did that on purpose because I wanted to break the reply into words. `words=( ${REPLY} )`. Is there a way to break a reply into an array of words without the file expansion?

Comment: Use `shopt -s noglob`